# Spring AOP is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am new to spring aop. I have the following classes.
***1. Interface***

```
public interface AccountService {

public void transferMoney(
        long sourceAccountId, long targetAccountId, double amount);

public void depositMoney(long accountId, double amount) throws Exception;

public Account getAccount(long accountId);

}
```

***2. Aspect Class***
    @Aspect
    public class TimeAOP {
    long startTime = 0;

```
@Pointcut("execution(* *.transferMoney(..))")// the pointcut expression
private void anyOldTransfer() {}// the pointcut signature

@After("anyOldTransfer()")
public void afterReturning(Object returnValue, Method method, Object[] args, Object target) throws Throwable {
    long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    String className = target.getClass().getCanonicalName();
    String methodName = method.getName();
    System.out.println("Execution of " + className + "#" + methodName
            + " ended in " + new BigDecimal(elapsedTime).divide(
            new BigDecimal(1000000)) + " milliseconds");

}

@Before("anyOldTransfer()")
public void before(Method method, Object[] args, Object target) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Starting");
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
}
```

}

***3. Configuration Class***

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xxx")
public class Ch2BeanConfiguration {
@Bean
public AccountService accountService() {
    AccountServiceImpl bean = new AccountServiceImpl();
    bean.setAccountDao(accountDao());
    return bean;
}

@Bean
public AccountDao accountDao() {
    AccountDaoInMemoryImpl bean = new AccountDaoInMemoryImpl();
    //depedencies of accountDao bean will be injected here...
    return bean;
}
}
```

***4. Test Class***

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext =
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Ch2BeanConfiguration.class);
    AccountService accountService = applicationContext.getBean("accountService",
            AccountService.class);
    System.out.println("Before money transfer");
    System.out.println("Account 1 balance :" + accountService.getAccount(1).getBalance());
    System.out.println("Account 2 balance :" + accountService.getAccount(2).getBalance());
    accountService.transferMoney(1, 2, 5.0);
    System.out.println("After money transfer");
    System.out.println("Account 1 balance :" + accountService.getAccount(1).getBalance());
    System.out.println("Account 2 balance :" + accountService.getAccount(2).getBalance());
}
}
```

***The output:***
Mar 06, 2016 12:27:05 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5d099f62: startup date [Sun Mar 06 12:27:05 EST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Before money transfer
Account 1 balance :10.0
Account 2 balance :20.0
After money transfer
Account 1 balance :5.0
Account 2 balance :25.0

**The AOP is never execute. Anyone can help me??**

Comment: is your aspect class is a spring bean ( has @Component annotation) ?

Comment: No, the Aspect class is not a spring bean, do I need to make it as a bean??

Comment: yes, take a look at section 10.2.2 (http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)

Comment: I added the @Component to the aspect class. However, when I run the program, I got the following error message.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using XML you need to return an Aspect bean from your @Configuration

```
@Bean
public TimeAOP timeAspect() {
    return new TimeAOP();
}
```

Comment: I tried it but I am getting the following error message org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

Comment: Thank. I figured it out. The parameter of the advice is incorrect.